# iframe not filled fully into col-sm

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

[image]I'm trying to embed Grafana panels into my website and have a problem with styling
How to make my iframes to fit inside the col-sm and not with a big margins (see attached screenshot)

My html is:

```
<p class="fs-1 fw-bold" id="internalSensors_1">
  Internal Beehive Sensors
</p>
</div>
```

```
    <div class="row">
      <!-- Internal temperature from Grafana-->
      <div class="col-sm">
        <div class="col-sm embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https:***" allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Internal humidity from Grafana-->
      <div class="col-sm">
      <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1">
        <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https:***" allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe>
         
      </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Internal pressure from Grafana-->
      <div class="col-sm">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1">
          <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https:***" allowfullscreen frameborder="0"></iframe> 
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do the following :

1. give a `.w-100` to the `<iframe></iframe>`
2. give a `.p-0` to `<div class="col-sm">`

Comment: no change, doesn't work

Comment: Any other style or bootstrap default styling can be conflicting.